# How to override neovim paste implementation?

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste, autocmd

I wanted to add some handler that is triggered whenever a paste happened. From what I know, there is no such a thing like autocmd for paste action. I have look into some possible solution such as overriding the `vim.paste` api such as below.

```lua
local function handler(overriden)
    return function (lines, phase)
        doSomething()
        overriden(lines, phase)
    end
end

vim.paste = handler(vim.paste)
```

But I noticed that the `doSomething` is only triggered when it is an external paste as mentioned in the docs.

```
"Paste" is a separate concept from |clipboard|: paste means "dump a bunch of
text to the editor", whereas clipboard provides features like |quote+| to get
and set the OS clipboard directly.  For example, middle-click or CTRL-SHIFT-v
(macOS: CMD-v) in your terminal is "paste", not "clipboard": the terminal
application (Nvim) just gets a stream of text, it does not interact with the
clipboard directly.
```

Is there any way I can implement one for all kind of paste?

Comment: YankRing does this by just defining a lot of mappings, after some complex code to find out which keybindings the user has set for these operations. It seems error prone, and not extendable. 

https://github.com/vim-scripts/YankRing.vim/blob/master/plugin/yankring.vim#L2376-L2396